# Why Parse Tree is not generated in my code for my sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, nlp, nltk

I am trying to create a context free grammar for general english sentences using python 3.7 and different nltk libraries. The code runs successfully, without any error for all the sentences.  But the tree isn't generated for all the sentences.
For example:
In following case:

```
q1 = "I shot an elephant in my pajamas"  
q2 = "Big Data is huge unstructured type of data"
```

Parse tree is generated for q1 and not for q2. And I don't understand why!

```python
st1="""
S -> NP VP
NP -> NNP|Det N|Det N PP
NN -> JJ NN|N
VP -> V JJ|V  NP|V S|V NP PP
PP -> P NP
"""+NNP+"\n"+Det+"\n"+N+"\n"+JJ+"\n"+V+"\n"+P

grammar1 = nltk.CFG.fromstring(st1)
sent = q1.split()
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar1)
for tree in rd_parser.parse(sent):
    print(tree)

print(st1)
print(grammar1)
```

Following is an output for q1. And same kind of parse tree needs to be generated for q2.

```
(S
  (NP (Det ) (N I))
  (VP
    (V shot)
    (NP (Det an) (N elephant) (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas))))))
(S
  (NP (Det ) (N I))
  (VP
    (V shot)
    (NP (Det an) (N elephant))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
```

You can see complete code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cfrpMR_tfVOE2IOpZ6Il4-qsizV0pirc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parse tree is not generated for q2 because the sentence is not in the language of the grammar, i.e., the goal symbol `S` does not derive the sentence.

You should write the sentence down on paper and then manually try to construct a parse tree for it. You'll find that it can't be done, and the specific ways in which it fails to be possible should suggest ways that the grammar needs to change in order to make it possible.

For example, here's one problem (not the only one): in the grammar, NNP derives both 'Big' and 'Data' (and nothing else derives either of them), so (roughly speaking) the sentence begins with `NNP NNP`, and yet `S` is incapable of deriving a form that starts with `NNP NNP`.